# Is it possible to undo a DD command

Tags: linux, dd

I am a newbie and was trying to move an image of win 7 onto a partition of a larger hardrive using clonezilla.
When I tried this the program told me that the new partition was mismatched gpt and mbr and I would need to correct the new drive.
Well it gave me the command of sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=512 count=1
Where sdx is changed to sdc for the drive.  Well idiotic me put in the sdc drive and hit enter before I realized it was the wrong drive.
Is it possible to undo this command? If so how?
Please and thanks

Comment: no, unless you have a backup copy of what was overwritten

Comment: Thanks....I might....you see the whole thing started when I used a partition program to move the original drive to a partition on the new drive in the hopes to have a dual boot system. However after I created the new partition and did a clone command it appeared as an unformatted partition and does not dual boot. I then thought the clonezilla program would allow me to do it. If I move the data from the new partition to the old drive do you think I would be able to use it?

Comment: @Liam0930 you are talking gibberish when you say move a drive to a partition.  And when you say "I created the new partition and did a clone command it appeared as an unformatted partition"   I don't see how you expect anybody to know exactly what you did. And I don't think you know what you did. I suggest that in future you do it far more slowly, take notes, and don't just double check things but triple check things if they are important. And make sure you study the terms you use to communicate so you don't say things that make no sense

Comment: Okay, thanks for your kind and generous response. I will do just what you say and triple check my work. Have a nice weekend.

Comment: remember that the common nickname of "dd" is "disk destroyer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dd is a non reversible command, but since you only deleted 1 sector you maybe able to rebuild it.

cgsecurity has a utility called testdisk that maybe able to rebuild it.

It will have to scan the WHOLE hard drive for lost partition, and it may take hours, but it should be able to recover the partition table.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

The first 512 bytes includes the bootloader for thevfisk and partition info.

It is not possible to "undo" a dd, however in this particular cade you may - with some difficulty - be able to recreate the important parts of the list info - and you should be able to - at minimum - get your meaningful data off.

You may be able to use Testdisk to refind and rebuild the partition info based on the filesystem locations.  Once this is fine, recreate the bootloader if required (how you do this depends on what wrote it, and is only necceasdary if yoy need to boot the drive.